# How to download in javascript zipfile when the data is large?

Tags: javascript, json, html, zip, jsonp

The data is over 2.5 MB, and the download is failed, if it's not a large data so it's succeed. in side server this is how i return the result

```
byte[] byt = outputStream.ToArray();
            string bas = Convert.ToBase64String(byt);
            var saveResult = this.Jsonp(bas);
            saveResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return saveResult;
```

and client side

```
 $.ajax({
            url: ServiceBaseURL + 'Home/DownloadFile?fileID=' + id,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                var strMimeType = 'application/txt';
                var strFileName = item.FileName;
                download("data:" + strMimeType + ";base64," + data[0].Dat, strFileName, strMimeType);
            }
        });
```

As i read about **download.js** it can only download a few hundred kilobytes of data. please any help